# perl simple concatenate

Tags: perl

In the following perl code how to concatenate pwd with a string.
In the following the output is in two different lines

```
   $pwd=`pwd`;
   my $string = $pwd . "/.somename";
   print "$string";
```

Comment: i had tried chomp but i get the following output 1/.somename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pwd=`pwd`;
chomp $pwd;
my $string = $pwd . "/.somename";
print $string;
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `\`pwd\`` - there's no reason to exec an external shell.

Answer (score 7):

You just did. It just so happens there's a newline character in the middle.

```
$pwd=`pwd`;
chomp($pwd);
my $string = $pwd . "/.somename";
print "$string";
```

That being said ... don't do that. You should use `cwd()`

```
use Cwd;

my $string = cwd() . "/.somename";
print "$string\n";
```

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that `pwd` and `cwd()` do not necessarily return the path to the directory the script is in.  If that's what you're after then [FindBin](https://metacpan.org/module/FindBin) is a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `chomp()`, like this:

```
my $pwd = `pwd`;
chomp($pwd);
my $string = $pwd . "/.somename";
print "$string";
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html

Comment: Not quite.  `chomp` returns how many chars it chomped, not the chomped string.

Comment: Hey, sorry about that @cHao; try using `chomp()` just by itself.